# Documented Methods of Retrieving System Information

Tags: cocoa, macos, sdk

I am looking for allowed or documented APIs that will let me gather basic system and hardware information (CPU Speed, RAM, etc..) for a OS X application, all the information is available in the system profiler, but I would much rather programmatically retrieve the data in a way which Apple will be OK with.

I have searched around and not really found anything, just wondering if anybody knows different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command-line tool [system_profiler](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html) which comes with every mac.

```
system_profiler -xml
```

will dump the same info the standard GUI system profiler app in a nice XML format.